# Using a proxy in a store is not working?

Tags: json, extjs, proxy, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

hi i create a store connect to contacts.json is not working ,here is my store

```
    Ext.define('senchatest.store.List', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'],
       alias: 'store.List',
    config: {
       model: 'senchatest.model.Contact',
       proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
      url: 'contacts.json',
       reader: {
      type: 'json'
       }
       }
       }
       });
```

and this is my modal

```
Ext.define('senchatest.model.Contact', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       config: {
       fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
       }
       });
```

and it is my json file

```
[
 { "firstName": "Tommy", "lastName": "Maintz" },
 { "firstName": "Ed", "lastName": "Spencer" },
 { "firstName": "Jamie", "lastName": "Avins" },
 { "firstName": "Aaron", "lastName": "Conran" },
 { "firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Kaneda" },
 { "firstName": "Michael", "lastName": "Mullany" },
 { "firstName": "Abraham", "lastName": "Elias" },
 { "firstName": "Jay", "lastName": "Robinson" },
 { "firstName": "Zed", "lastName": "Zacharias "}
 ]
```

what is wrong its not display a data

instead of proxy directly use data it work

eg:

```
Ext.define('senchatest.store.List', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'],
       alias: 'store.List',
    config: {
       model: 'senchatest.model.Contact',
       data :[
              { "firstName": "Tommy", "lastName": "Maintz" },
              { "firstName": "Ed", "lastName": "Spencer" },
              { "firstName": "Jamie", "lastName": "Avins" },
              { "firstName": "Aaron", "lastName": "Conran" },
              { "firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Kaneda" },
              { "firstName": "Michael", "lastName": "Mullany" },
              { "firstName": "Abraham", "lastName": "Elias" },
              { "firstName": "Jay", "lastName": "Robinson" },
              { "firstName": "Zed", "lastName": "Zacharias "}
              ]


       }
       });
```

This code is working but proxy code is not working what is a issue

Answer (score 0):

Modify the model as below ( `config` property isn't necessary ) :

```
Ext.define('senchatest.model.Contact', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
      {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'}
   ]
});
```

EDIT :

I create a Fiddle on Sencha, check it out.

[JSON Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3c1)

Comment: check modified answer

Comment: i think u create using extJs check in sencha touch 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader, it has a perfect example how you can do what you desire

Store

```
Ext.define('senchatest.store.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.List',
    // use the model @Oğuz Çelikdemir suggested
    model: 'senchatest.model.Contact',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'contacts.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'contacts'
        }
    },
});
```

contacts.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "contacts": [
        { "firstName": "Tommy", "lastName": "Maintz" },
        { "firstName": "Ed", "lastName": "Spencer" },
        { "firstName": "Jamie", "lastName": "Avins" },
        { "firstName": "Aaron", "lastName": "Conran" },
        { "firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Kaneda" },
        { "firstName": "Michael", "lastName": "Mullany" },
        { "firstName": "Abraham", "lastName": "Elias" },
        { "firstName": "Jay", "lastName": "Robinson" },
        { "firstName": "Zed", "lastName": "Zacharias "}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
   autoLoad: true,
   proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   url : 'contacts.json'
    }
```